# suppress printing of B series of notes in reledmac

Tags: printing, reledmac

Using reledmac, I write two series of critical footnotes, \Afootnote and \Bfootnote.  How can I suppress or disable the B series of notes while leaving them in the source?  That is, I want the A series to be printed but neither the lemmas nor notes for the B series to be printed.  Sometimes I want to print the text with Afootnotes only, sometimes with both A and B.

If I load reledmac with the option [series={A}] (while leaving the B series footnotes in place), then errors appear complaining that \Bfootnote is an undefined control sequence.

I can't find anything in the manual on this; if I've missed it, just point me to the page or section.

Comment: Indeed there is no option for this. You can't symply redefine `\Bfootnote`, as reledmac check for consistency (an `\edtext` must have an associated footnote.). So the solution is to open an issue on github (see handbook about that). I shall be able to provide such option, quite easy to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The v2.36.0 of reledmac, just send on CTAN, add a `\Xnonote` hooks.

To disable B series : `\Xnonote[B]` ; to disable A series : `\Xnonote[A]` ; to disable A and B : `\Xnonote[A,B]` ; to disable all series : `\Xnonote`.